# AS3 / Why does my label change if i disable it? (Radiobutton)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Why changed my label color and size when I disable it? And how would I be able to solve it?

And if this is not possible, how would I then be able to resolve it the best?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit disabled state clip of your radio button component. Double click on your radio button then you will see all the states of it as in the image[image]

Change the graphics as you want.

Hope it helps.

Try this,

```
var hit:RadioButton = event.currentTarget as RadioButton;

var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.font = "Arial";
format.size = 23;
format.bold = false;
format.color = 0x5D205E;
format.letterSpacing = 0; 
hit.label = " Hello";
hit.setStyle("textFormat", format);
```

Comment: I can't change the label colour is disabled.

Comment: My text if it is enabled is red but when I disable the radio button again become small and gray.

Comment: Are you using custom component(MovieClip)?

Comment: I did change the graphics but i think not.